# copy of python list b = a[:] not works as expected, why?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm searching for fast way to copy a object or list.
Found following suggestions

`b = a[:]`  <-- fast
`b = a.copy()`  <-- slower

Yes, it worked but yet problem remains.
if I change the content of `b` then the content of a` is also changed, why?

--- following is my trial code ---

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros([4,4])
>>> a
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x16b21959a30'
>>> b = a
>>> hex(id(a)), hex(id(b))
'0x16b21959a30', '0x16b21959a30'
>>> c = a[:]
>>> hex(id(a)), hex(id(b)), hex(id(c))
('0x16b21959a30', '0x16b21959a30', '0x16b1fc54800')
```

Here, we found address of `c` is different from others. (address of `a` and `b` is same)

So now try to change content of `c` and verify content of `a`.

```
>>> c[0][0]
0.0
>>> c[0][0] = 11
>>> c
array([[11.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> a
array([[11.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> b
array([[11.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I changed only `c[0][0]`, but I see `a[0][0]` and `b[0][0]` is also changed.
Why?

Comment: You are not working with a python `list`, but rather, ` numpy.ndarray` object. For python lists, this: `b = a[:] <-- fast b = a.copy() <-- slower` is not true. And `a[:]` doesn't make a copy for `numpy.ndarray`, but rather, a *view*.

Comment: @Rakesh that duplicate target is talking about `list` objects, not `numpy.ndarray` objects, which have slightly different semantics (slicing does not copy the underlying buffer, i.e. it creates a view)

Comment: You can use `copy.deepcopy` to recursively copy all mutable objects in the collection: `from copy import deepcopy; b = deepcopy(a)`

Comment: You need to understand **shallow copy** and **deep copy** concepts. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

Comment: @ReutSharabani no, that isn't needed. This is `numpy`, a different beast regarding these things.

Comment: Correct your title and text.  Copy for lists and numpy arrays is different.

Comment: `b` is the same array as `a`.  `c` is a `view`, a new array object (different `id`) but shared data buffer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a [:] does not cause a real memory copy.
Only pointers are copied.

copy () causes a real copy.
So it takes a long time.

I don't know the internal structure, but deepcopy () is the fastest.

See the experiment code below.

```
from copy import deepcopy;
import numpy as np
import time

a = np.zeros([5000,5000])

start = time.time()
c = a[:]
print("time :", time.time() - start)
# 5.245208740234375e-06

start = time.time()
d = a.copy()
print("time :", time.time() - start)
# 0.33116960525512695

start = time.time()
e = deepcopy(a)
print("time :", time.time() - start)
# 0.15706825256347656
```

Comment: No, **this is not a python list but a numpy array**. There are no pointers involved.

Comment: With numpy arrays, `a[:]` just returns a `view`, so is very fast.  When I use `ipython` `timeit`, `deepcopy` is slightly slower than copy.  `deepcopy` is only useful in `numpy` if the array is an object dtype.  It's the same as `copy` for numeric arrays.

Comment: Thank you for telling me. I learned something new! And sorry for sharing the wrong information. Thanks!